# Regex between a string

Tags: regex

Example:

I have the following string

```
a125A@@THISSTRING@@.test123
```

I need to find `THISSTRING`. There are many strings which are nearly the same so I'd like to check if there is a digit or letter before the `@@` and also if there is a dot (`.`) after the `@@`.

I have tried something like:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+@@?)(.+?)(.@@)
```

But I am unable to get it working

Comment: It would be `([a-zA-Z0-9]+@@)(.+?)(@@\.)`.

Comment: Define _"unable to get it working"_. What have you tried? What is your theory?

Comment: Thanks but this will find
a125A@@THISSTRING@@.
according to http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: @J.Doe: Updated my answer with Javascript example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use look behind and look ahead:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]@@).*?(?=@@\.)
```

https://regex101.com/r/i3RzFJ/2

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html
neither does with c++ std::regex.

Comment: Well it seems that it doesn't support look-behind. You can use the other answer with the non-capturing groups or [find a library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) that supports it

Answer (score 0):

> But I am unable to get it working.

Let's deconstruct what your regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]+@@?)(.+?)(.@@)` says.

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+@@?)` match **as many `[a-zA-Z0-9]`** followed by a `@` followed by **optional `@`**.

`(.+?)` any character as much as possible but fewer times.

`(.@@)` any character followed by two `@`. Now `.` consumes `G` and then `@@`. Hence `THISSTRING` is not completely captured in group.

---

Lookaround assertions are great but are little expensive.

You can easily search for such patterns by matching `wanted` and `unwanted` and capturing `wanted stuff` in a capturing group.

**Regex:** `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]@@)([^@]+)(?:@@\.)`

**Explanation:**

`(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]@@)` Non-capturing group matching `@@` preceded by a letter or digit.

`([^@]+)` Capturing as many characters other than `@`. Stops before a `@` is met.

`(?:@@\.)` Non-capturing group matching `@@.` literally.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vyRJ9o/2/)**

---

**Javascript Example**

```js
var myString = "a125A@@THISSTRING@@.test123";
var myRegexp = /(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]@@)([^@]+)(?:@@\.)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> check if there is a digit or letter before the @@

I assume you mean a digit / letter before the **first** `@@` and
check for a dot after the **second** `@@` (as in your example).

You can use the following regex:

```
[a-z0-9]+  # Chars before "@@", except the last
(?:        # Last char before "@@"
  (\d)     # either a digit - group 1
  |        # or
  ([a-z])  # a letter - group 2
)
@@?        # 1 or 2 "at" chars
([^@]+)    # "Central" part - group 3
@@?        # 1 or 2 "at" chars
(?:        # Check for a dot
  (\.)     # Captured - group 4
  |        # or nothing captured
)
[a-z0-9]+  # The last part
# Flags:
# i - case insensitive
# x - ignore blanks and comments
```

How it works:

- Group 1 or 2 captures the last char before the first `@@`
  (either group 1 captures a digit or group 2 captures a letter).
- Group 3 catches the "central" part (*THISSTRING*,
  a sequence of chars other than `@`).
- Group 4 catches a dot, if any.

You can test it at https://regex101.com/r/ATjprp/1

Your regex has such an error that a dot matches **any** char.
If you want to check for a **literal** dot, you must escape it
with a backslash (compare with group 4 in my solution).